# DomDocument::LoadXML(): Entity 'bull' not defined in Entity

Tags: php, utf-8, domdocument

```
$xml =  '<tag> &bull; </tag>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

$xml is utf8 encoded string which is saved in db while exporting it as XML, I am getting the following warning:

```
DomDocument::LoadXML(): Entity 'bull' not defined in Entity
```

If using loadHTML instead of loadXML getting following warning:

```
DomDocument::LoadXML(): Entity 'tag' not defined in Entity
```

Comment: So further, what you want to achieve?

Comment: want to avoid warning

Comment: Although these errors are valid, but still if you want to suppress them use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);`

Comment: what would be the better way to export XML with UTF-encoded data